# Structure of Parity Check Matrix of Non-Systematic Tensor Product Codes

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, tensor-products, coding-theory

Let $[n_i,k_i,d_i]_q$ for $i=1,2,\dots,r$ be a set of $r$ non-systematic linear codes over $\Bbb F_q$ with $k_i \times n_i$ generator matrix $G_i$ each and $n_i \times (n_i - k_i)$ parity check matrix $H_i$ each. Then we know that the the tensor product code with generator matrix $G_1 \otimes G_2 \otimes \dots \otimes G_r$ provides a linear code with parameters $[n_1n_2\dots n_r,k_1k_2\dots k_r,d_1d_2\dots d_r]$ with $k_1k_2\dots k_r \times n_1n_2\dots n_r$ generator matrix $G$. What is structure of the parity check matrix? It is unclear how the parity matrix should be since the parity matrix has dimensions $n_1n_2\dots n_r \times (n_1n_2\dots n_r-k_1k_2\dots k_r)$ with any pair of $d_1d_2\dots d_r$ rows linearly dependent and the non-systematic nature of the code implies $G_i \neq [I_i|P_i]$ where $I_i$ is $k_i \times k_i$ identity matrix.

Is the complexity of construction of parity matrices exponential in $r$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an image cropped out of a slide set I prepared for a presentation to former coworkers at Nokia.

[image: product code check matrix]

An explanation is due. This is what a check matrix of a product of two codes looks like. Here $H$ is a check matrix of the first factor code, and $K$ is a check matrix for the second factor. If $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{n_1}$ are the natural basis vectors of the ambient binary space of the former factor code, and $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{n_1}$ are a similar basis for the ambient space of the latter factor, then the bit ordering that I use corresponds to $b_1\otimes c_1$,
$b_2\otimes c_1$, $\ldots,b_{n_1}\otimes c_1$,  $b_1\otimes c_2$,
$b_2\otimes c_2$, $\ldots,b_{n_1}\otimes c_2$, $\ldots,\ldots$,
 $b_1\otimes c_{n_2}$,
$b_2\otimes c_{n_2}$, $\ldots,b_{n_1}\otimes c_{n_2}$.

The check equations in $H$ affect all the $n_2$ groups of $n_1$ bits (with a fixed $c$-factor). Similarly the check equations in $K$ affect all the $n_1$ groups on $n_2$ (with a fixed $b$-factor). It looks like in my image $n_1=10$ and $n_2=8$.

The reason why this works is that the upper (grey) block of the check matrix
defines the code $C_1\otimes \mathbb{F}_2^{n_2}$, and the lower (green) block
defines the code $\mathbb{F}_2^{n_1}\otimes C_2$. Together these check equations
define the intersection of those two subspaces, i.e. $C_1\otimes C_2$.

Caveat:
Here the number of $H$-checks is $r_1n_2$ and the number of $K$-checks is
$r_2n_1$, where $r_i=n_i-k_i$ is the number of redundant bits in the factor codes. Here
$$
n_1n_2-(r_1n_2+r_2n_1)=(k_1+r_1)(k_2+r_2)-(r_1(r_2+k_2)+r_2(k_1+r_1))=k_1k_2-r_1r_2
$$
This is less than the rank $k_1k_2$ of the product code, so we see that there will be several linear dependencies among the rows
of this huge matrix. If this is a concern for you, then you may need to follow up this with a row reduction step. The way I used these codes, it was (in a way) a benefit to have these redundant checks.

You need to iterate this construction to get check matrices for a product of more than two codes.

There is also a general method for encoding a product code given the check matrices $H$ and $K$. That encoding method allows us to simply write the payload bits to certain positions, but it is in a sense a 2-dimensional process as opposed to the usual 1-dimensional way of calculating the parity bits as functions of information bits. This is outlined in the three following figures.

I use the $(16,11,4)$ extended Hamming code $C$ as both $C_1$ and $C_2$. Here is a version of its check matrix (may be a bit non-standard version, but they are all equivalent, so):

[image]

The arrows in columns $7,11,13,14,15$ indicate the choice that these should be the check positions (start indexing from zero, as this is engineers/programmers we are talking about). Notice that those five columns form an indentity matrix, so they serve well in the role of check bits.

Next I present individual **words** of the product code as $16\times 16$ matrices. Such a matrix is a word of the product code $C\otimes C$, iff all the columns and all the rows are words of the code $C$. There are $k_1k_2=11^2$ information bits. I put these in positions where both the row and the column index is an information position. These could be filled in any which way we want.
The way I did the filling in this example is quite regular. I did it this way simply to make it easier for me to do the steps that follow. Also, this way it is easier to check that the process was done correctly. The question marks indicate a check position.
[image]

In the first encoding stage I simply fill in the rows where the necessary 11 information bits are already known. This gives me 11 filled rows leaving the check rows with `?'.
[image]

In the second encoding stage I then fill in the columns. As all the columns already have the 11 information bits there, this poses no problems.
[image]

This second stage created 5 rows that where previously filled with question marks. By (bi-)linearity these new rows will automatically also be words of $C$! In this sense each of those 5 rows thus also satisfies 5 extra parity check equations. These are the $r_1r_2$ extraneous check equatios azimut asked about.

My advice actually is to not use parity check matrices at all, when the code is very long (in thousands of bits). This applies with extra force to product codes, because encoding can be carried out more efficiently using $H$ and $K$ alone.

Comment: Hi Jyrki: Thankyou again. Interesting. I would not even thought for the non-systematic case such a diagram existed. Would you mind sharing your slides?

Comment: Is there a succint mathematical - by this I mean a symbolic and algebraic - description?

Comment: (+1) Very nice answer! One more question: Is there a "natural" way to describe the $r_1r_2$ dependencies among the check rows?

Comment: @azimut, JAS: I added a bit extra explaining the encoding process and the origin of those redundant check equations. I'm a bit reluctant to share the entire file set. My own non-disclosure agreement expired in 2012, but my coworkers/coauthors were left behind, and they may have continued to develop the ideas in other slides. I don't want to compromise that work, as I don't know about their current status (and the status of this project). Also, this tiny bit of secrecy makes my past life sound a bit more exciting than what it actually was :-)

Comment: Another image from the same slide set is in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/158624/11619). There a trellis representation of the length 16 extended Hamming code is discussed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Would you by any chance know the complexity of construction of the parity check matrix? Supposing we take the tensor product $r$ times. Is it exponential or polynomial time in $r$?

Comment: @J.A. The size of the matrices grows exponentially as a function of $r$, so I would guess that forces it to be exponential. However, doing the encoding (filling in of the question marks) is exponential as a function of $r$, but its complexity is $r$ times the number of payload bits. Meaning that it is ok. I tested this quite a bit with $r=3$ and the $(16,11,4)$-code. It worked splendidly in the sense that with iterative decoding the performance of the code in AWGN was comparable to turbo/LDPC. The design is not very flexible though, and engineers need that. IDK if they solved that problem.