# Tensor Product Codes and their Characteristics

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, coding-theory

Let's say we have 2 linear codes, $C : \mathbb{F}^{k_1} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n_1} $ and $R : \mathbb{F}^{k_2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n_2} $.

We define $ T : \mathbb{F}^{k_1 \times k_2} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n_1 \times n_2} $ as $C \otimes R$.

Meaning: given a matrix $M$ of dimenstions $ k_1 \times k_2$ we code the rows of $M$ with $R$ and the collums of $M$ with $C$.

How can we prove the following:

Every matrix $K'$, where the rows of $K'$ are valid codewords of $R$ and the columns are valid codewords of $C$, can be obtained by coding a matrix $K$ using $T$.

Idea:

I thought about showing that $K'$ is a linear combination of valid codewords and thus a valid codeword aswell, but I can't seem to find a valid linear combination.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/489313/11619).